# About as_view function in Flask

Tags: python, mongodb, listview, flask

The code in this [example](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/write-a-tumblelog-application-with-flask-mongoengine/):

```
posts.add_url_rule('/', view_func=ListView.as_view('list'))
posts.add_url_rule('/<slug>/', view_func=DetailView.as_view('detail'))
```

I don't understand the parameter passed in the function `as_view` above, what is the purpose of `list`and `detail` here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It creates the endpoint for the routing system, so you can use `url_for('posts.list')` or similar, the [API docs are here](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.views.View.as_view).

Comment: If you're wondering what a flask endpoint is, check out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19261833/what-is-an-endpoint-in-flask