# Flask werkzeug.routing.BuildError if endpoint method name not same as route

Tags: flask, jinja2, werkzeug

I am using Flask with blueprints to build routing endpoints.
The following works fine:

```
@my_view.route('/send_email', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def send_email():
    print(">>send_email()")
```

wtf form:

```
<form role="form" action="{{ url_for('my_view.send_email') }}" method="post">
```

However if I change the method name such as below, I get an error "werkzeug.routing.BuildError: Could not build url for endpoint 'my_view.send_email'."

```
@my_view.route('/send_email', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def some_other_method_name():
    print(">>some_other_method_name()")
```

Why do I need to name the method to be the same as the route for this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

url_for uses the function *name* to construct the url path. change

```
<form role="form" action="{{ url_for('my_view.send_email') }}" method="post">
```

to

```
<form role="form" action="{{ url_for('my_view.some_other_method_name') }}" method="post">
```

and you should be good to go. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19261833/what-is-an-endpoint-in-flask) for a great explanation on how flask routing works.