# what does endpoint mean in flask-restful

Tags: python, rest, flask-restful

I defined some resource called `WorkerAPI` using flask-restful and the plan is to process POST request from `/api/workers/new` and GET request from `/api/workers/`. When using the following code

```
api.add_resource(WorkerAPI, '/api/workers/new')
api.add_resource(WorkerAPI, '/api/workers/')
```

I get errors:

> AssertionError: View function mapping is overwriting an existing endpoint function: workerapi

Then I tried to use the following, which seems to work, although I don't know why it works.

```
api.add_resource(WorkerAPI, '/api/workers/new', endpoint='/workers/new')
api.add_resource(WorkerAPI, '/api/workers/', endpoint='/workers/')
```

It looks like redundant information to me though. It seems the site works as long as the two `endpoint`s are defined as different strings. What does `endpoint` mean here?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The thing is that the `add_resource` function registers the routes with the framework using the given `endpoint`. If an `endpoint` isn't given then Flask-RESTful generates one for you from the class name.

Your case is `WorkerAPI`, the endpoint will be`workerapi` for these two methods, better make `endpoint` explicit and avoid to have conflicting endpoint names registered.

For what's endpoint, you can refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19261833/what-is-an-endpoint-in-flask) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

**'endpoint'** is actually an identifier that is used in determining what logical unit of your code should handle a specific request.

So, an URL path is mapped to an endpoint and then an endpoint is mapped to a view function in your flask app.

In your case, when you are explicitly defining your endpoints for your resources, it helps the flask app internally to map it efficiently to a list of routes, while when your are not explicitly defining it, flask takes some default value, as explained by @Tiny.D, in the above answer.